# How avoid variable approximation at the time of conversion?

Tags: delphi

I am having one `Delphi XE2` Project. In my project, I am having `MainForm`, `Label01`, `Label02`, `Label03`, `Label04`, `Label05`, `Label06`, `Edit01`, `Edit02`, `Edit03`, `Edit04`, `BitBtn01`, `BitBtn02`, `Timer01` and `Timer02`.

I am trying to implement the following:

After `Button Click` the `Brightness` of `Label01.Font.Color` will be increased or decreased continuously as like as 'Microsoft's has done this thing after completion of any work in Windows 7 in Taskbar'.

So my logic is : on `BitBtn01.Click` the `Label01.Font.Color` will be be converted into `HSB Color Model` according to the procedure named as `RGBToHSV`. If the `Brightness` is less than 100%, then it will be incremented by `Timer01`. After reaching the `Brightness` at 100%, it will be decremented by `Timer02` upto 25%. Everytime the `Brightness` will update `Label01.Font.Color` according to the procedure named as `HSVToRGV` keeping `Hue` and `Saturation` constant. These procedures works according to `Color Conversion Algorithm`.

According to my requirement I have written the following codes :

```
unit ApplicationWizard01;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Math;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    BitBtn01: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn02: TBitBtn;
    Edit01: TEdit;
    Edit02: TEdit;
    Edit03: TEdit;
    Edit04: TEdit;
    Label01: TLabel;
    Label02: TLabel;
    Label03: TLabel;
    Label04: TLabel;
    Label05: TLabel;
    Label06: TLabel;
    Timer01: TTimer;
    Timer02: TTimer;
    procedure BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer01Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer02Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure HSVToRGB(Const H, S, V: Real;  {  'H' In '000' To '001', 'S' In '000' To '001', 'V' In '000' To '255'  }
                   Out R, G, B: Real);   {  'R' In '000' To '255', 'G' In '000' To '255', 'B' In '000' To '255'  }
const
  SectionSize = 60/360;
var
  F: real;
  P, Q, T: real;
  Section: real;
  SectionIndex: integer;
begin
  if H < 0 then
    begin
      R:= V;
      G:= R;
      B:= R;
    end
  else
    begin
      Section:= H/SectionSize;
      SectionIndex:= Floor(Section);
      F:= Section - SectionIndex;
      P:= V * ( 1 - S );
      Q:= V * ( 1 - S * F );
      T:= V * ( 1 - S * ( 1 - F ) );
      case SectionIndex of
        0:
          begin
            R:= V;
            G:= T;
            B:= P;
          end;
        1:
          begin
            R:= Q;
            G:= V;
            B:= P;
          end;
        2:
          begin
            R:= P;
            G:= V;
            B:= T;
          end;
        3:
          begin
            R:= P;
            G:= Q;
            B:= V;
          end;
        4:
          begin
            R:= T;
            G:= P;
            B:= V;
          end;
        else
          begin
            R:= V;
            G:= P;
            B:= Q;
          end;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure RGBToHSV(Const R, G, B: Real;  {  'R' In '000' To '255', 'G' In '000' To '255', 'B' In '000' To '255'  }
                   Out H, S, V: Real);   {  'H' In '000' To '001', 'S' In '000' To '001', 'V' In '000' To '255'  }
var
  Range: real;
  RGB: array[0..2] of real;
  MinIndex, MaxIndex: integer;
begin
  RGB[0]:= R;
  RGB[1]:= G;
  RGB[2]:= B;

  MinIndex:= 0;
  if G < R then MinIndex:= 1;
  if B < RGB[MinIndex] then MinIndex:= 2;

  MaxIndex:= 0;
  if G > R then MaxIndex:= 1;
  if B > RGB[MaxIndex] then MaxIndex:= 2;

  Range:= RGB[MaxIndex] - RGB[MinIndex];

  if Range = 0 then
    begin
      H:= 0;
      S:= 0;
      V:= R;
    end
    else
      begin
        case MaxIndex of
          0:
            begin
              H:= (G-B)/Range;
            end;
          1:
            begin
              H:= 2 + (B-R)/Range;
            end;
          2:
            begin
              H:= 4 + (R-G)/Range;
            end;
        end;
        S:= Range/RGB[MaxIndex];
        V:= RGB[MaxIndex];
        H:= H * (1/6);
        if H < 0 then H:= 1 + H;
      end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer01.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer01.Enabled := false;
  Timer02.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  HueStandardisationFactor = 360;
  SaturationStandardisationFactor = 100;
  BrightnessStandardisationFactor = 100/255;
var
  H, S, V, R, G, B: Real;
begin
  R := 98;
  G := 128;
  B := 33;

  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(Round(R), Round(G), Round(B));

  Edit01.Text := FloatToStr(Round(R)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(G)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(B));

  RGBToHSV(R, G, B, H, S, V);

  Edit02.Text := FloatToStr(Round(H*HueStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(S*SaturationStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(V*BrightnessStandardisationFactor));

  Label02.Caption := 'Starting RGB Value :    ' + '(' + FloatToStr(R) + '  ' + FloatToStr(G) + '  ' + FloatToStr(V) + ')';
  Label03.Caption := 'Starting HSV Value :    ' + '(' + FloatToStr(Round(H*HueStandardisationFactor)) + '  ' + FloatToStr(Round(S*SaturationStandardisationFactor)) + '  ' + FloatToStr(Round(V*BrightnessStandardisationFactor)) + ')';
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer01Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  HueStandardisationFactor = 360;
  SaturationStandardisationFactor = 100;
  BrightnessStandardisationFactor = 100/255;
var
  Brightness : Integer;
  H1, S1, V1, R1, G1, B1: Real;
  H2, S2, V2, R2, G2, B2: Real;
begin
  R1 := GetRValue(Label01.Font.Color);
  G1 := GetGValue(Label01.Font.Color);
  B1 := GetBValue(Label01.Font.Color);

  RGBToHSV(R1, G1, B1, H1, S1, V1);

  Brightness := Round(V1);
  Brightness := Brightness + 1;
  if Brightness >= 255 then
    begin
      Timer01.Enabled := false;
      Timer02.Enabled := true;
    end;

  H2 := H1;
  S2 := S1;
  V2 := Brightness;

  Edit03.Text := FloatToStr(Round(H2*HueStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(S2*SaturationStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(V2*BrightnessStandardisationFactor));

  HSVToRGB(H2, S2, V2, R2, G2, B2);

  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(Round(R2), Round(G2), Round(B2));

  Edit04.Font.Color := RGB(95, 25, 255);
  Edit04.Text := FloatToStr(Round(R2)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(G2)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(B2));
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer02Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  HueStandardisationFactor = 360;
  SaturationStandardisationFactor = 100;
  BrightnessStandardisationFactor = 100/255;
var
  Brightness : Integer;
  H1, S1, V1, R1, G1, B1: Real;
  H2, S2, V2, R2, G2, B2: Real;
begin

  R1 := GetRValue(Label01.Font.Color);
  G1 := GetGValue(Label01.Font.Color);
  B1 := GetBValue(Label01.Font.Color);

  RGBToHSV(R1, G1, B1, H1, S1, V1);

  Brightness := Round(V1);
  Brightness := Brightness - 1;
  if Brightness <= 25 then
    begin
      Timer01.Enabled := true;
      Timer02.Enabled := false;
    end;

  H2 := H1;
  S2 := S1;
  V2 := Brightness;

  Edit03.Text := FloatToStr(Round(H2*HueStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(S2*SaturationStandardisationFactor)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(V2*BrightnessStandardisationFactor));

  HSVToRGB(H2, S2, V2, R2, G2, B2);

  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(Round(R2), Round(G2), Round(B2));

  Edit04.Font.Color := RGB(15, 135, 255);
  Edit04.Text := FloatToStr(Round(R2)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(G2)) + '        ' + FloatToStr(Round(B2));
end;

end.
```

The required links are as follows:

1. HSVToRGB Procedure - hxxp://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=133111
2. RGBToHSV Procedure - hxxp://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=133111
3. Color Conversion Algorithm - hxxp://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

Replace 'x' with 't'.

[**Here is the download link of my project**](https://hotfile.com/dl/236143585/8965401/Application_Wizard_01.7z.html)

My coding is correct and compiles perfectly.

**But the problem is that after running the program for few times the `Hue` and `Saturation` gets changed (yet it should not happen so) though I have used all the required varible as `Real`**.

So the colour is shifted from the original color.

I am unable to find it out to apply more precision so that the color shifting my be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the original color somewhere and make your calculations always on that value. The intermediate values should only be used for display and not for calculating the next step. Conversion errors tend to add up over time.

Comment: I don't know how that can be possible?

Comment: Build a class that will handle this and interacts with a TLabel instance

Comment: Please any one download my project and see.

Comment: I see - you are doing it the wrong way. My answer and Sir Rufos comment should guide you to the solution.